# How do I break down this function?

Tags: python

I have a question regarding a code in python.

```
def myst(val1, val2):
 if(val1 and val2):
  return 'a'    
elif(val1 and not val2):
 return 'b' 
elif(not val1 and val2):
 return 'c' 
else:
 return "d"
```

Question:

```
myst(not(not False and True), not(not False or False))
```

What is the correct answer?

I tried to break down the function, so it would become
myst(not(True, True), but that was incorrect..

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Its from an exam..

Comment: Well `not False` is `True`, `not True` is `False` and `not (... and ...)` and `not (.... or ...)` from [De Morgan laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is respectively `not .. or not ...` and `not .. and not ..`. Then you grab a paper and pen and solve it.

Comment: myst(False,False) results "d"

Comment: I would simplify the inputs. Looks like (false, false), but it’s 6am and I’m not really awake yet.

Comment: aah okey, cause i got myst not(True,True) which equals myst(False, False), so that is correct? Thank you for all the response!

Comment: brackets first. go inner brackets first, and keep solving outwards.

Comment: it shall me `myst(False, False)`

Comment: what you wrote there, `myst not(True,True)` is *not* correct. you shouldn't be getting that. the result however is `myst(False, False)` so *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

First you should evaluate the boolean expressions at the method call.

`val1` = `not(not False and True)` ==> `not(True and True)` ==> `not(True)` ==> `False`

`val2` = `not(not False or False)` ==> `not(True or False)` ==> `not(True)` ==> `False`

Thus both `val1` and `val2` are going to be False in this method call.

Following the if conditions, the none condition matches when both of the arguments are `False` thus the else statement will be chosen, and the final return value will be 'd'.

Answer (score 0):

The Output will be `d` AND the process is given below:-

[image]

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

myst(not(not False and True), not(not False or False))

lets take first argument which is "not(not False and True)"

***not(not False and True) => not(True and True) => not(True) => False***

now take second argument which is "not(not False or False)"

***not(not False or False) => not(True or False) => not(True) => False***

so, both arguments are False
The only condition satisfies for both false arguments is last else:
so it will return "d"

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce the statement as you would do in algebra, it will become clear:

```
myst(not(not False and True), not(not False or False)) ... parentheses first
myst(not(True and True), not(True or False))           <-- "not X" has priority
myst(not(True), not(True))
myst(False,False)
"d"
```

If you think of your parameters as bits composing a number, you can actually use the two parameters as an index to your letters and write the function more concisely:

```
def myst(val1, val2): return "dcba"[2*val1+val2]

False, False = 00 = 0 --> d
False, True  = 01 = 1 --> c
True,  False = 10 = 2 --> b
True,  True  = 11 = 3 --> a
```